# PHP - Regex for a string of special characters

Tags: php, regex

Morning SO. I'm trying to determine whether or not a string contains a list of specific characters.

I know i should be using [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) for this, but my regex knowledge is woeful and i have been unable to glean any information from other posts around this site. Since most of them just want to limit strings to a-z, A-Z and 0-9. But i do want some special characters to be allowed, for example: `! @ £` and others not in the below string.

Characters to be matched on: `# $ % ^ & * ( ) + = - [ ] \ ' ; , . / { } | \ " : < > ? ~`

```
private function containsIllegalChars($string)
{
    return preg_match([REGEX_STRING_HERE], $string);
}
```

I originally wrote the matching in Javascript, which just looped through each letter in the string and then looped through every character in another string until it found a match. Looking back, i can't believe i even attempted to use such an archaic method. With the advent of json (and a rewrite of the application!), i'm switching the match to php, to return an error message via json.

I was hoping a regex guru could assist with converting the above string to a regex string, but any feedback would be appreciated!

Comment: Er... The Unicode catalogue contains more than 100,000 characters. Are you sure you only want to filter out the few ones you list? Don't you prefer a white list approach?

Comment: Fortunately, in this case - a black list is adequate.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Regexp for a "list of disallowed character" is not mandatory.

You may have a look at [`strpbrk`](http://php.net/strpbrk). It should do the job you need.

Here's an example of usage

```
$tests = array(
    "Hello I should be allowed",
    "Aw! I'm not allowed",
    "Geez [another] one",
    "=)",
    "<WH4T4NXSS474K>"
);
$illegal = "#$%^&*()+=-[]';,./{}|:<>?~";

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    echo $test;
    echo ' => ';
    echo (false === strpbrk($test, $illegal)) ? 'Allowed' : "Disallowed";
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

http://codepad.org/yaJJsOpT

Comment: This would do the job to be fair - would it be more efficient than `preg_match`?

Comment: Despite this not being what i asked for - it's a much better solution to use and therefore i have accepted your answer, thanks!

Comment: Noticing this old comment, the test case given was not optimized for `preg_match`. [Here's a better one](http://eval.in/15753). This doesn't change `strpbrk`'s efficiency but gives a true value for `preg_match`

Answer (score 12):

```
return preg_match('/[#$%^&*()+=\-\[\]\';,.\/{}|":<>?~\\\\]/', $string);
```

Comment: Works 100% for the question i asked, thanks Arnold. Looking at `strpbrk` though, it may win over my initial thoughts of using `preg_match`

Answer (score 4):

I think what you're looking for can be greatly simplified by including the characters that you want to allow like so:

```
preg_match('/[^\w!@£]/', $string)
```

Here's a quick breakdown of what's happening:

- [^] = not included
- \w = letters and numbers
- ! @ £ = the list of characters you would also like to allow

Answer (score 3):

```
$pattern = preg_quote('#$%^&*()+=-[]\';,./{}|\":<>?~', '#');

var_dump(preg_match("#[{$pattern}]#", 'hello world')); // false
var_dump(preg_match("#[{$pattern}]#", 'he||o wor|d')); // true
var_dump(preg_match("#[{$pattern}]#", '$uper duper')); // true
```

Likely, you can cache the `$pattern`, depending on your implementation.

(*Though looking outside of regular expressions, you're best of with [`strpbrk`](http://php.net/strpbrk) as mentioned here too*)

Comment: You're right, `strpbrk` is much better for what i need. But i hadn't seen `preg_quote` previously, it appears to be quite a handy little function, so thanks for pointing it out!