# looping through string to remove pairing bracket until all pairs are replaced

Tags: php, regex

I am still working on my reg exp. This is a bit complicated for me.

I want to match string where in one `< should have a partner >` but the `< should be followed by >` where in this `>< should fail` because `< >` should be the pattern that `<<>>` is acceptable

`preg_match('/[^\w<>]/', $string)`

Demo:[link](https://regex101.com/r/iJwN6t/2)

The thing I can come up with is the idea that `<` should be or should have a partner `>`

Update:

I used this to remove the string with partner:

```
function replacewhole($string){
        $string = str_replace("<>","",$string);

        if(preg_match_all("/<>/", $string)){
            self::replacewhole($string);
        }

        return $string;
    }
```

Calling from:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($expressions); $i++){
   $expressions[$i] = self::replacewhole($expressions[$i]);
}
```

But the inner string match only is removed

Comment: How did you come up with `[\w!<>]` ?

Comment: im using that page to test it showed result. Like I said im still learning reg exp if its wrong please do correct IM still working on it right now

Comment: See also [regular expressions: how to find the bit between the "<>" in an email](//stackoverflow.com/q/4373508) or [Get text between and outside angle brackets in PHP](//stackoverflow.com/q/48226861) - Though it's still unclear if the extra spaces are supposed to be present, or if it should just match words e.g.

Comment: @mario im following the format from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13970412/php-regex-for-a-string-of-special-characters) wasnt able to copy paste properly.

Comment: @mario great ideas

Comment: Ah ok. Those samples were more for filtering. What you're looking for are "in between" regex matching patterns. Check out http://regexp.info/ for some better introductions.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `<.*?>`? `[^\w<>]` is looking for a non-word character, `<`, or `>` anywhere in a string. https://regex101.com/r/HNVBn0/1/

Comment: @mario can you show how to match exactly "<>" in reg ex?

Comment: @user3783243 what does that do it is also shown in the link provided by mario

Comment: `.` is any non-new line character. `*` is a quantifier meaning allow 0 or more of the previous character/group. `?` makes the quantifier stop at the first occurrence of the next character, `>`

Comment: @user3783243 can you help me match `<>` anywhere in the string?

Comment: What happens with the `<.*?>`? Can you provide more samples?

Comment: @user3783243 i cant use it. What my plan is match `<>` in the string and remove it and loop again until I remove all `<>`. The example you gave gets what is inside `<>`

Comment: `how to match exactly "<>" in reg ex?` → well that would be `preg_match("/<>/"` → to only ever match a literal `<>` with nothing in between. Is this really where this question is going now?

Comment: @mario i need all so i used `preg_match_all("/<>/", $string)` my plan is just match the string remove it and loop again until im left with string that has no match but this still not working

Comment: The question is very confusing. Can you please post the string you start with and what the end result should be? It sounds like `str_replace` and/or `strpos` could be used

Comment: @mario I just updated the question with the related code. As I develop I sort of think this is a much simplier solution. And I didnt bother posting another question

Comment: Still need to know what `$string` is.. `preg_match` isn't needed with what you are doing http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php will do the same thing and be minimally more efficient (and you won't run into regex issues).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to match any `<nested <stuff>>`, try `preg_match_all` with [recursion](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html)

```
/<(?>[^><]*(?R)?)*+>/
```

`(?R)` recurses the full pattern - [See this demo and explanation at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/NFlEjq/1)

---

To check all string consists of none or balanced `<>` only, try `preg_match`

```
/^(<(?>[^><]*(?1)?)*>|[^><]+)++$/
```

`(?1)` is a [call](https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) to the pattern in first [group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) - [Another demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/NFlEjq/2/)